# How to include a custom/local Gatsby plugin and build and deploy on Netlify?

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a Gatsby generated website which I deploy using Netlify.

I've followed the tutorial listed [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/pixabay-source-plugin-tutorial/) to create a custom/local source plugin in a very similar fashion.

The custom plugin obviously has its own `package.json` file and therefore requires `npm i` for things to work when imported via the root level `gatsby-config.js`.

What's the easiest way of getting the dependencies to install for my custom plugin on my Netlify deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpliest, I think you can instruct yarn (or npm) to cd into your plugin folder then run install.

In netlify, you can change the default build script from the default `gatsby build` to `yarn build` (or the npm equivalent).

Then, in your root package.json, in `scripts`, add this:

```
"install-plugin": "cd ./plugins/your-plugin-name && yarn",
"build": "yarn install-plugin && gatsby build"
```

It's not the most elegant solution when you have more than a few custom plugins; for that case I think a custom post install script could work.

---

Alternatively you could also add all dependencies of the plugin directly to the root package.json!

Comment: I like this solution for a single package, it does the job without over complicating things.

Answer (score 3):

Gatsby works well with yarn. Netlify supports using yarn, so you have the **option** to setup yarn workspaces.

Yarn workspaces have the added advantage to allow you to start creating themes in Gatsby later when you are ready to use them. Yarn will use the configuration to maintain the `node_modules` link for the plugin as if you had installed it using npm. Later, you can always publish your plugin to npm and use it as a module for other sites.

- Move your Gatsby site into its own directory (for example `gatsby-site`)
- Create/move the source plugin to it's own location (for example `gatsby-source-someplugin`)
- Use `yarn workspace gatsby-site add gatsby-source-someplugin` to add the dependency to the site for the source plugin
- Create a simple `package.json` at the root of your project as below

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Your Name <your@email.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "workspaces": [
    "gatsby-site",
    "gatsby-source-someplugin"
  ]
}
```

- Make sure to run `yarn` and build your `yarn.lock` file locally and push it to your repository. It will let Netlify know you are using yarn and will install and configure yarn for you.

***Note:*** Make sure to keep the netlify.toml in the root location if you have one. Also change the deploy path to the `gatsby-site/public` directory. Change your build command to use the workspace (i.e. `yarn workspace gatsby-site build`). Test the build command locally should prove everything is working.

Comment: I'll keep this for reference, it seems like a great solution for when things get more complicated.

Comment: Yeah. Your chosen answer as the solution is not something I would do, but solves your use case. This answer is there for the person who will be setting up a full solution with more than one plugin and/or themes. The chosen answer will get real complicated quickly when adding other packages and creating a monorepo. I do agree, there is more than one answer to the question.